# Audit changes made to an owned entity Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have two entities Employer and Address

```
public class Employer
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; private set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public string City { get; private set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; private set; }
    public string AddressLine { get; private set; }
}
```

I have a method to track changes on both entities for audit purposes. I would like to track the changes on the owned type but I get

"**System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'Address' on entity type 'Employer' is being accessed using the 'Property' method, but is defined in the model as a navigation property. Use either the 'Reference' or 'Collection' method to access navigation properties.'**"

Any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: Do you have code like this `context.Entry(Address).Property(` . If yes replace it with `context.Entry(Address).Reference(`.

Comment: Tried that but it doesn't solve my problem